# How to have group of html elements below another group of CSS-floating elements, without adding CSS to first element group

Tags: html, css

### What I'm trying to do:

I want to create a simple webpage that looks something like this:

```
[L block]        [R block 1][R block 2]

Body text.
```

Specifically:

- `L block` MUST be left aligned.
- `R block 1` and `R block 2` MUST be right aligned and dynamic -- if the page is resized, they will stay on the right side of the page.

  - *(Assume that the page width will always be wide enough for the "blocks" and some space in between them.)*
- `L block`, `R block 1`, and `R block 2` MUST all on the same horizontal level.
- `Body text` MUST be below all the above.
- `Body text` SHOULD NOT need any CSS formatting.
- "Top Blocks" SHOULD be wrapped in a `nav` element.
- The different "Top Blocks" SHOULD be able to be different elements, e.g. `h1`, `h3`.

I know that one way this could work is to give `float: left;` and `float: right;` to the "blocks", and then give the body text `clear: both;`. For example:

```html
      <div class="nav-div">
      <nav>
        <h1 class="nav-left">
            [Left Block]
        </h1>
        <h3 class="nav-right">
            [Right Block 1]
        </h3>
        <h3 class="nav-right">
            [Right Block 2]
        </h3>
      </nav>
      </div>
      
      <div class="p-div">
      <p>
        Inside p tag.
      </p>
      </div>
```

```css
.nav-left {
    float: left;
}

.nav-right {
    float: right;
}

.p-div {
  clear: both;
}
```

(Code at https://jsfiddle.net/fe2bx5zc/)

But this isn't what I'm trying to do -- I don't want to have to add CSS to the body text (`.p-div {clear: both;}`). *(For context, this isn't some actual requirement -- I'm just trying to better understand how HTML/CSS work...)*

### My question:

Is it possible to accomplish "What I'm trying to do" -- create that simple webpage without adding any CSS to the body text?

If not, how come? *(If this is the case, I'd also appreciate, but don't expect, any suggestions for other approaches with different pros/cons compared to how I did it in the jsfiddle above. I have no idea if what I did is "good" or "bad" practice...)*

If so, how could I do it?

*I'd also appreciate, but don't expect, any explanation regarding how floating and/or Flow Layout works in CSS/HTML and why making something go left/right can also make it go down. I've reviewed the documentation, but I'm struggling to understand this.*

Comment: _If_ you use float, then `clear` on the body text will be required; that's how `float` is designed to work (it is intended for use on images so that text can flow around images similar to how print media displays images in news articles).

Comment: See https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/10/the-mystery-of-css-float-property/ for a primer on CSS float (though note it was written 14 years ago... despite that, most of it remains accurate/relevant), and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float for more technical information on it (MDN is an excellent resource in general for any HTML or CSS questions at a technical level).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try using `display: flex` rather than `float`, it really makes aligning things on a line easy.
I suggest visiting the W3Schools website to visualize how to use this wonderful property.

```css
nav {
display:flex;
justify-content: space-between;
}
nav div{
display:flex;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div>
    <h1 class="nav-left">
      [Left Block]
    </h1>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <h3 class="nav-right">
      [Right Block 1]
    </h3>
    <h3 class="nav-right">
      [Right Block 2]
    </h3>
  </div>
</nav>
      
<div class="p-div">
  <p>Inside p tag.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: The css-tricks guide on flexbox is amazing!